# Let G be a Group and $a,b \in G$. If $a$ and $b$ commute and $|a|$ and $|b|$ are finite. What can be possible values for $|ab|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I want to find the order of $ab$, which I have tried to find as follows. 
Let order of $a$ be $|a|=m$ and that of $b=|b|=n$ 
Let $x=\text{lcm} (m,n)$,  then clearly $\exists$ integers $ s , t $ such that $x=ms$ and $x=nt$
Thus, $(ab)^x=a^x b^x=a^{ms}b^{nt}=e$ 
 If $y\lt x$ then, $(ab)^y=a^yb^y=b^y (\text{or} a^y)$, if $y$ is some multiple of $m$, less than $x=ms$(or, if $y$ is multiple of $n$ but less than $nt$. Either way,$(ab)^y\ne e$
Therefore, $|ab|=x$=lcm$(m,n)$

Is the above reasoning correct? Can you please help me find the right solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what if $a = b^{-1}$?

Comment: @MeesdeVries, In that case, $m=n$ however, $(ab)=e$ so $|ab|=1\ne$lcm $(m,m)$. It suggests that $|ab|$ can be any divisor of $x$? I think no. Because, let $x$ be even(=2k) then $x/k=2$ should be $|ab|$, which is not true as $(ab)^2=a^2b^2 \ne e$. [Assuming $m\ne n]$.

Comment: See the duplicate for the problem of your proof. We only have that $|ab|$ divides $lcm(n,m)$.